# saltstack lxd-formula howto

Tags: salt-stack, lxd

I want to install with salt lxd containers, and I got only errors. I'm beginner with salt.
I've cloned lxd-formula from GitHub, and I put folders under `/srv/salt`:

```
/srv/salt/lxd
/srv/salt/_modules
/srv/salt/_states
```

and I modify file_roots like this:

```
file_roots:
  base:
   - /srv/salt
   - /srv/formula/lxd-formula
```

and I try to install a container with this config `test/test4.sls`:

```
lxd:
 containers:
  local:
   ubuntu-xenial:
   running: True
   source: xenial/amd64
```

and used this command:

```
salt '*hv-04*' state.sls test.test4
```

and I've got this error:

```
State 'lxd' in SLS 'test.test3' is not formed as a list
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misunderstood how the configuration and utilization of formulas work.

You are not creating a state, you are just configuring it. All you did in `test/test4.sls` should be in the **pillar**. Read more about [*configuring formulas using pillar*](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html#configuring-formula-using-pillar) to understand better how it works

After configuring it, just run the state for container creation which, according to the [doc](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/lxd-formula#lxd-containers), is `lxd.containers`:

```
salt '*hv-04*' state.sls lxd.containers
```

Comment: Yes I misunderstood, but after I read a lot, I can't do it. I create a pillar, with container data, and I apply the stat lxd.containers, but the salt only check and install necesary packages, don't create the container.

Comment: @Akos Check if the pillar you've created is being assigned to your minion. Does the command `salt '*hv-04*' pillar.items` retrieve the pillar correctly?

Comment: A got an empty response.

Comment: -hv-04.xxxxxxxxxx.lan:
    ----------

Comment: That's the problem. All the configuration for the formula is done through the pillar. Make sure you follow the directions on the pillar [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/index.html#declaring-the-master-pillar) and the command `pillar.items` return the desired values before running the state. Probably your `top.sls` is not properly configured.

Comment: @Akos any news?